# How to Create a Repo For One File From an Existing Repo?

Tags: git

I wrote a script (let's say `make.bat`) in a Git repo containing hundreds of other files. The commits of `make.bat` always have only file `make.bat` involved, but are together with commits of other files.

Original repo (contains `make.bat` along with hundreds of other files, 8 commits):

```
commit A - initial commit
commit B
commit C - add make.bat
commit D
commit E - update make.bat
commit F
commit G - update make.bat
commit H
```

How can I create another repo that only has file `make.bat` and all histories of it?

New repo (contains only one file `make.bat`, 3 commits):

```
commit C - add make.bat
commit E - update make.bat
commit G - update make.bat
```

Comment: Do you just want to ignore all the other files? If so, just add `*` to the top of the _.gitignore_ file then, on another line, `!make.bat`. This will ignore every file except for _make.bat_.

Comment: @JacobLee Thank you, but I didn't put my question clear and have edited my question. What I want is a new repo.

Comment: Are you aware that, at the moment, your commits C, E, and G have _all the other files_ too? You do not have _any_ commits consisting of "just one file". That is not how Git works. When you say "The commits of make.bat always have only file make.bat involved", that's just false.

Comment: @matt What I understand is, commit C does not have all the other files. Instead, it only have the information that `make.bat` was added. It's true other files were present when `commit C` was commited, but there is no change of other files in commit C.

Comment: @lxvs: that's not true. Each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file (or more precisely, of every file that the commit has, which seems kind of redundant, but if you explicitly *remove* a file, the new snapshot will lack that file). We tend to *view* commits by having Git compare them to previous commits: here, Git only tells us about the files that *changed*, between those two commits. This cuts down on the noise. But every commit still contains every file.

Comment: When we use `git cherry-pick` (which `git rebase` does internally), Git does this same kind of comparison: old vs new, what changed? Git can then apply the same change to *some other* commit; if you start with a base of "no files at all", and copy the "add one file" operation from its commit, you get a new commit with "one file". If you then copy the "change one line in that one file" commit, you get another new commit with just the one file in it, still.

Comment: [bfg](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) looks promising. It might not be the quickest answer, but clone your repository, then use bfg to erase all files that are not `make.bat` from history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is absolutely true that no files were changes in any of the `make.bat` commits, then just duplicate your project folder and then say

```
git rebase -i --root
```

In the editor, delete all lines representing commits that are not `make.bat` commits. Save and quit the editor.

Now you have a repo consisting entirely of the history of `make.bat`.

Comment: Better `git reflog expire --all --expire=now` and `git gc --agressive --prune=now` afterwards.